# How can i get CPU and Mainboard serial number with Qt/C++?

Tags: c++

I want to use CPU and Mainboard serial number for licensing. please help me how can i implement this operation in QT

Comment: What platform and what OS?  Not all systems that Qt runs on have CPUs with a serial number and not all mainboards provide unique readable serial numbers.

Comment: Licenses are much more commonly tied to MAC addresses of one (or more) network adaptors on the system

Answer (score 4):

In general, what you are trying to do is not possible for privacy reasons (at least on x86).

The only x86s CPUs to ever have a software-accessible serial number was the Pentium III. It was controversial, so Intel took it out of all later processors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_III#Controversy_about_privacy_issues

It's sometimes possible to read motherboard serial #s, but in a lot of cases, they return meaningless (non-unique) numbers like 0123456789.

What you can do instead is to query the model numbers. For the CPU, you can do that via the `cpuid` instruction (`__cpuid()` and `__cpuidex()` intrinsics in Windows).
For the motherboard, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Qt doesn't provide a functionality like this.

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/8287

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/3080

Maybe this can give you some alternative thoughts
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=355953